# Fail to to open the activiti explorer

Tags: ant, activiti

I have downloaded the activiti 5.10 and i run the demo setup, by typing

```
Ant demo.start
```

In the CMD command line and it gave me that "Build Successful". but when the activiti-explorer link opened automatically it showed me the following error:-

**HTTP Status 404 - /activiti-explorer

type Status report

message /activiti-explorer

description The requested resource (/activiti-explorer) is not available.**

So what might be going wrong?
BR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_06\bin to my PATH and it worked fine.